# Use cases for hstore vs json datatypes in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2, hstore

In Postgresql, the hstore and json datatypes seem to have very similar use cases. When would you choose to use one vs. the other? Initial thoughts:

- You can nest with json; you can't with hstore
- Functions for parsing json won't be available until 9.3

Comment: Why off topic? Seems fairly specific and relevant to me.

Comment: I assumed people though it should have been asked at dba.stackexchange.com so I re-posted it there and got a good answer: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/41431/use-cases-for-hstore-vs-json-datatypes-in-postgresql

Comment: Not sure why developers aren't supposed to know about types. Important thing is that you got your answer, I suppose.

Answer (score 2):

The json type is just a string. There are no built in functions to parse it. The only thing to be gained when using it is the validity checking.

Edit for those downvoting: This was written when 9.3 still didn't exist.It is correct for 9.2. Also the question was different. Check the edit history.

Comment: 9.3 will have additional JSON functions.